# Adding a custom Tcl procedure to a SWIG generated Tcl module?

Tags: tcl, swig

I'm trying to replace an old Tcl interface to C++ using SWIG. Here is an example class:

```
class test {
  std::string str;
 public:
  test(const char * s):str(s) {}
  void print() const {std::cout << str << std::endl;}
};
```

and here is the standard way to use it:

```
load ./example.so example
test s "this is a test string"
s print
```

But I want to preserve the simplicity of the old interface which does not use the `""`. I've found that I can do something like:

```
load ./example.so example

proc TEST {args} { test [lindex $args 0] [lrange $args 1 end] }

TEST s2 this is another test string
s2 print
```

Which looks simple and works flawlessly, however, of course, I cannot have the `proc` definition in the user script. I'm not sure where else I could place it. Is there a way to put it in the .i file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you can put this in your `.i` file:

```
%init %{
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "proc TEST {args} { ... }");
%}
```

That will insert a call to `Tcl_Eval` (which will make the procedure) into your module's initialization function, and as long as the `interp` context is available there (WARNING! Check this!) then you'll get everything nicely packaged.

If you've got lots of code, consider calling `Tcl_EvalFile` instead, or calling Tcl code that will `source` the script code (necessary if you've got a need for complex scripting to locate the file to read).